# difference of using substr with like operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT SUBSTR(gram_panchayat,1,6) GP FROM tw_master WHERE gram_panchayat LIKE 'B%';

SELECT gram_panchayat FROM tw_master WHERE gram_panchayat LIKE 'B_____';
```

what is the difference between these 2 select statements.

Comment: Run them both and you'll see the difference (if there is any).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (You can remove the unrelated tag.)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(gram_panchayat,1,6) GP FROM tw_master WHERE gram_panchayat LIKE 'B%';
```

will get (up to) the first six characters of any value that starts with a 'B', however long it is - as `%` is a wildcard for any number of characters. You could end up with results with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 characters. Longer values will be truncated by the `substr()` call.

```
SELECT gram_panchayat FROM tw_master WHERE gram_panchayat LIKE 'B_____';
```

will only retrieve values that are exactly six characters long - as `_` is a wildcard for a single character. Applying `substr()` to that therefore wouldn't make any difference to the result, as it can't be longer than six characters anyway.

If the column has values that are longer or shorter than six characters then the second query will return fewer rows, as it's a more restrictive match. If all the values are exactly six characters then the results will be the same - but then the `substr()` in the first query would also be unnecessary.

---

You can see the difference between the queries with some made-up sample data of varying lengths:

| GRAM_PANCHAYAT |
| --- |
| ABCDEF |
| B |
| BA |
| BAB |
| BABC |
| BABCD |
| BABCDE |
| BEDCBA |
| BABCDEF |
| BABCDEFG |
| BABCDEFGH |
| BABCDEFGHI |

The first query returns all the rows starting with 'B', with some truncated:

| GP |
| --- |
| B |
| BA |
| BAB |
| BABC |
| BABCD |
| BABCDE |
| BEDCBA |
| BABCDE |
| BABCDE |
| BABCDE |
| BABCDE |

The second query only returns those that start with 'B' and are exactly six characters long:

| GRAM_PANCHAYAT |
| --- |
| BABCDE |
| BEDCBA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tk_uHH6B?hide=8)